# How to delegate to an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with methods `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.  I would like to create a "delegator" object with these same methods that simply calls the corresponding method on each object in the array.  My current solution below seems to have unnecessary repetition (i.e., the definition of functions `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are nearly identical.  It would also be nice if I didn't have to remember to add a method to the delegator object every time I added a method to the "delegated" objects.  Is there a better way to prepare a delegator object?

```
Delegator = (function () {
    "use strict";

    var objectList = [];

    var callOnAll = function(functionName, args) {
        objectList.forEach(function(logger) {
            logger[functionName].apply(logger, args);
        });
    };

return {
   add : function (handler) { objectList.push(handler); };

   a: function() { callOnAll('a', arguments); };
   b: function() { callOnAll('b', arguments); };
   c: function() { callOnAll('c', arguments); };
 };
}());
```

I'm aware of `__noSuchMethod__`; but, it appears to be non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more dynamic approach that doesn't require you to know the method names in advance:

```js
var Delegator = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var objectList = [];

    var callOnAll = function(functionName, args) {
        objectList.forEach(function(logger) {
            if (typeof logger[functionName] === 'function') {
                logger[functionName].apply(logger, args);
            }
        });
    };
    
    function addMethods(handler) {
        Object.keys(handler).forEach(function (key) {
            if (!(key in obj) && typeof handler[key] === 'function') {
                obj[key] = function () { callOnAll(key, arguments); };
            }
        });
    }           

    var obj = {
       add : function (handler) { 
           objectList.push(handler); 
           addMethods(handler);
       }
    };

    return obj;
}());

Delegator.add({
    a: function () { console.log('called a()!'); },
    b: function () { console.log('called b()!'); }
});

Delegator.add({
    a: function () { console.log('called a()!'); },
});

Delegator.a();
Delegator.b();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of an improvement:

```
Delegator = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var objectList = [];

    var callOnAll = function(functionName, args) {
        objectList.forEach(function(logger) {
            logger[functionName].apply(logger, args);
        });
    };

    var obj = {
       add : function (handler) { objectList.push(handler); };
    };

    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].forEach(function(methodName) {
      obj[methodName] = function() {callOnAll(methodName, arguments);};   
    });
    return obj;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather have a pure `class` approach.

```
(function (global) {
  'use strict';

  //Using `api` instead of `interface` as `interface` is a reserved word
  var Delegator = global.Delegator = function Delegator (handlers, api) {
    //You can optionally pass desired API
    this.api = api || [];
    this.handlers = [];

    if (handlers) {
      this.add(handlers);
    }
  };

  Delegator.prototype.setApi = function setApi (handler) {
    for (var prop in handler) {
      if (typeof handler[prop] === 'function') {
        this.api.push(prop);
        this[prop] = this.call.bind(this, prop);
      }
    }
  };

  Delegator.prototype.call = function call (method) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var result = [];

    this.handlers.forEach(function forEachHandler (handler) {
      result.push(handler[method].apply(handler, args));
    });

    return result;
  };

  Delegator.prototype.check = function check (handler) {
    if (! this.api) {
      return false;
    }

    var missingMethods = this.api.filter(function forEachMethod (method) {
      return ! (method in handler) || typeof method !== 'function';
    });

    return missingMethods.length && missingMethods;
  }

  Delegator.prototype.add = function add (handler) {
    if (Array.isArray(handler)) {
      handler.forEach(this.add, this);

      return this;
    }

    //First time adding an object
    if (! this.api.length) {
      this.setApi(handler);
    }

    //This is purely optional and can be removed
    var missingMethods = this.check(handler);

    if (! missingMethods) {
      throw new Error('Given handler has missing or invalid methods:' + missingMethods);
    }

    if (this.handlers.indexOf(handler) !== -1) {
      return this;;
    }

    this.handlers.push(handler);

    return this;
  };
}(typeof window === 'undefined' ? this : window));

var obj1 = {
  'x': function () {return 'x1'},
  'y': function () {return 'y1'},
}

var obj1 = {
  'x': function () {return 'x1'},
  'y': function () {return 'y1'},
}

var obj2 = {
  'x': function () {return 'x2'},
  'y': function () {return 'y2'},
}

var obj3 = {
  'x': function () {return 'x3'},
  'y': function () {return 'y3'},
}

var delegate = new Delegator([obj1, obj2]);

console.log(delegate.x()); // -> ['x1', 'x2']

delegate.add(obj3);

console.log(delegate.y()); // -> ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']
```